# Using Arduino microcontrollers without board

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new into Arduino. So if I program the microcontroller using the Arduino board and once it is doing what I want can I just take the microcontroller out of the board and use the microcontroller itself? If so could you please guide me to some tutorials on how to use it?

Comment: You prise the chip out of the board? What part are you wondering about?

Comment: @NickGammon Yes I meant taking the chip out and use it as you explained on your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @per1234 please stop making trivial, unnecessary edits to old questions.  It adds nothing, but uselessly bumps them to the top of the main page, stealing attention from topics that legitimately deserve attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a post about a [breadboard Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard) - in that I demonstrate the minimal amount of parts you need to use the controller (which is not much).

Example of wiring it up:

[image: Minimal Arduino]

If you want to use an external crystal or resonator you can add that to the board like this:

[image: Crystal on board]

8 MHz crystal shown, but you could use 16 MHz. Or change the fuses and use the internal oscillator.

---

Schematic showing how you could (if you wanted) add an ICSP header and an FTDI header:

[image: Simplified Arduino schematic]

Comment: One quibble regarding that first picture being minimal ... what's your rationale for having a 10KΩ pullup on Reset instead of depending on the internal pullup? (30K-60KΩ, per Electrical Characteristics specs table 30.2, DC Characteristics)

Comment: There were reports of unreliability with only the internal pull-up, but certainly you could try omitting it. I notice you didn't ask me about the diode. ;)

Comment: I agree though, for *minimal* you may as well omit the 10k resistor.

Comment: I assume the diode keeps charge on C3 from pushing reset up to about 10V as RTS goes from low to high and also allows C3 to discharge so RTS can pull Reset low for automatic reset in programming

Comment: That's roughly it. In certain cases /Reset was being pushed high enough for the chip to enter High Voltage Programming mode, and thus was unresponsive to attempts to program it via the bootloader.